# Odoo 10 how to calculate the total debt of partner

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to calculate the total debt of partner_id, with all his debit on every his invoice

as an example:

In `Accounting\Customer Invoices` I have a

[image]

when I click on `bbb` opens

[image]

when I click on the report, in my case `Automatski racun`

[image]

I want to enter in the field `Vaš ukupan dug` the total debt of all accounts that `bbb` has

And can you tell me how to iterate over all partner_id eg. in the Journal Items
Because I tried this way to get a total of `bbb` debt, but I did not know how to iterate

If I'm not clear enough or you need more information, please let me know

Comment: Can you include an example of the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the code.

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
    def set_customer_credit(self):
        self.custom_field = self.partner_id.credit
```

Comment: I apologize for not giving full information
I edited the question

Comment: @Pavlo Escobar This did not help me, but thank you for the answer

Comment: Add the above code in account.invoice , and customize the invoice report by calling that field at anywhere you want ! This code will work.